# MySql Update if exists insert if not

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to insert new to the table or to update the previous one in the same query.I can solve it with a bit of php code but my goal is to make it all in sql.

**The problem**

My app has names in different languages, I can add new languages to it.When i add new languages the translations for my products raise.
My goal is to send the script information ,and if two columns are same than the data should be updated, but if they are not they should be updated.

Here is some of my query:

```
"INSERT INTO product_name(link,product_id,language)
VALUES(:link,:product_id,:language) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
link=:link,product_id=:product_id,language=:language"
```

This query above solves one portion of the problem, but when i want to change the link it adds new data.My goal is to change the link ,and if the product_id and language are same in that row than it should be updated,if not than a new one shall be added.Unique wont solve the problem since i need to use same languages and id's in the table.

Comment: you can't reuse the same named placeholder in PDO.

Comment: Please check your answer before you post anything.....

Comment: Um........ huh?

Comment: Yes, he can, if he has EMULATED_PREPARES on.

Comment: @Arslan so do you? ^ how do I/we know you do or not?

Comment: $stmt->execute(array(":link"=>$link,":exercise_id"=>$exercise_id,":language"=>$language));

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie sure, but we don't know that, least "I" don't. And I asked them if they did or not.

Comment: Well, it's ON by default, so... chances are it's on. And no, you didn't ask anything, that I can see? At least not when you categorically stated that he can't reuse the named placeholders.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Let me rephrase then *"you can't reuse the same named placeholder in PDO if EMULATED_PREPARES is not ON"*, there, how's that? and the OP never bothered answering to my comment in asking if it is on or not. IMHO; it was a snarky remark on their part and is presumptuous in having "me" know that it is for them. Well I have news for them; they're over there and I'm over here ;-)

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie  *"And no, you didn't ask anything, that I can see?"* -  My *"@ Arslan so do you? ^ how do I/we know you do or not?"* was in relation to your comment with the caret pointing to your comment; that was a question asking for it. So my comments were valid questions asking for clarification.

Comment: Guys whats happening?Chill...

Comment: we're not arguing @Arslan I'm only stating what I wrote and asked valid questions. Many times I/we see questions where they use the same named placeholders and we don't know if EMULATED_PREPARES is on or not, that's why I said that and corrected myself with junkfoodjunkie's additional comment ;-) some have errors for it when it's not ON and we don't know that.

Comment: I'm sorry.....Will you forgive me?:D

Comment: Relax my bad you were right

Comment: @Arslan everything's cool ;-) I was expecting a response but did not get one. I'll take this as experience the next time and ask if EMULATED_PREPARES is on or not before posting; just a slight communication breakdown. And yes :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just need a unique constraint on `(product_id, language)` -- and no unique constraint or primary key on all three columns.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unq_productname_product_language ON product_name(product_id, language);
```

This requires that the *pair* of values be unique, not each one individually.

Then this should do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO product_name(link, product_id, language)
    VALUES (:link, :product_id, :language)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE link = VALUES(link);
```

Notice that this version uses `VALUES(link)`.  This uses the value being inserted in the statement.  I think that is clearer than repeating the expression.